# Sum of an irreducible representation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, representation-theory

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $\mathfrak{X}$ be an irreducible $F$-representation of $G$ over an arbitrary field. Show that $\sum\limits_{g\in G}\mathfrak{X}(g) = 0$ unless $\mathfrak{X}$ is the principal representation.

I know that there are many different proofs of this fact, but I wanted to prove this statement on my own, and I have not yet seen a proof similar to mine (although I may be wrong). But is this proof correct?

*Unfortunately, as it has already turned out, this proof doesn't work for an arbitrary field, but it is probably true for a field with characteristic $0$!!!*

***Proof:***

Let $\mathfrak{X}$ be the principal representation, then by definition $\forall g\in G\Rightarrow \mathfrak{X}(g) = 1_{F}$. Then $$\sum\limits_{g\in G}\mathfrak{X}(g) = \sum\limits_{g\in G}1_{F} =|G|\cdot 1_{F}$$
Now let $\mathfrak{X}$ not be the principal representation. Let $T = \sum\limits_{g\in G}\mathfrak{X}(g)$. Note that $\forall a \in G$
$$\mathfrak{X}(a)T = \mathfrak{X}(a)\sum\limits_{g\in G}\mathfrak{X}(g) = \sum\limits_{g\in G}\mathfrak{X}(ag) = T.$$
Then it follows that $T^2 = |G|\cdot T$. Then the polynomial $x^2 -|G|x$ is annulling for $T$. Then the Jordan form of $T$ (up to permutations of Jordan cells) can take the following forms:

Either $|G|\cdot I$ ; or zero matrix; or a matrix with several units diagonally (not completely filling it), and the rest of all values are zero, and multiplied by $|G|$. Note that only the zero matrix among all these types of matrices has a trace equal to zero!

Let $\chi$ be the character associated with $\mathfrak{X}$. Consider the following expression $$S = \sum\limits_{g\in G}\chi(g) = [\chi, 1_G] = 0.$$
The last equality holds because $\chi\in Irr(G)$ and $\chi \neq 1_G$.

Since $\chi(g) = tr(\mathfrak{X}(g))$ and $tr(A + B) = tr(A) + tr(B)$ for any matrices $A$ and $B$, we get that $S = tr(T) = 0$. But only the zero matrix among the possible candidates for the role of $T$ had a zero trace. So $T = 0$, which was required to be proved. $\blacksquare$

Comment: If $F$ is an arbitrary field, then it may have nonzero characteristic. How would you be sure that the zero matrix is the only matrix having a trace of zero in that case?

Comment: Yes, I really jumped to conclusions. In this case, my reasoning is not entirely correct.

Comment: I have a module-theoretic proof that I cooked up if you'd like to see that.

Comment: I know one proof that exactly works for absolutely any field. It would be interesting to see how you proved this statement.

Answer (score 3):

I think the module-theoretic approach works nicely here. Let $V$ be the corresponding $F[G]$-module to this representation. If you are reading Isaacs' book, then this equivalence between $F$-representations and $F[G]$-modules is explained in the first chapter. We have that the set

$$
I := \{ \lambda \cdot \sum_{g \in G} g \; | \; \lambda \in F \}
$$
is a subalgebra of the group algebra $F[G]$ (routine to verify). Now, since $\mathfrak{X}$ is irreducible, we have that $VI$ is either $0$ or all of $V$. We see that $VI = 0$ implies that right multiplication by $\sum_{g \in G} g$ is the zero linear transformation, and the matrix of this linear transformation is zero, that is, $\sum_{g \in G} \mathfrak{X}(g) = 0$. Otherwise, $VI = V$, and it follows that right multiplication by any $g \in G$ on $V$ is the identity transformation, so when $VI = V$, the representation is the principal representation.

Comment: Yes, my other proof is pretty similar to yours!